# How to find the largest regular shape inside irregular convex polygons in 2D

Tags: geometry, circles, computational-geometry, polygons

I want to find a way that can find a regular or common shape (e.g a circle, triangle, square or rectangle) that has the maximum area inside different irregular 2D polygons.

From this [article](https://www.mathopenref.com/polygonincircle.html), it shows it is possible to find the largest circle of regular polygons. But it is not possible to find the largest circle of irregular polygons. I am wondering if there are any methods to find the largest regular shape inside irregular polygons?

[image: Examples]

If not, are there any good methods that can find a relatively large inside shape.

I thought a way of finding a relatively large inside shape.

`#For one irregular polygon P
centroid = calculate_the_centroid(P)
for length in a range of incremental values:
    draw a inshape using the centroid and the length
    if inshape is inside the polygon:
        max_inshape = inshape
        continue
    else:
        break
max_inshape is a relatively large inside shape`

However, this method can be computationally expensive and the performance is highly depended on setting the range of values. Any thoughts are welcome! Thank you guys very much.